Do file names have any effect on SEO
Do the physical filenames have any effect on SEO?

css files
html files
javascript files
image files
folder names

Thanks!

Hey hope this helps,

Naming image files something descriptive is crucial to SEO and helps search
engines understand what the image depicts

HTML/CSS/JavaScript files don't directly affect SEO but do play a
role in  overall performance that in turn affects SEO.

Folder names and structure often appear in the URL and should be a clean
and descriptive, if content is logically organized into folders and
subfolders it  will help search engines understand the hierarchy and
relationship between pages


